# PHP autoload and set_include_paths

Tags: php, autoload

I have a small app that uses a few different clases.  In each file i am setting the include paths to the relevant folders and declaring an autoload function.

This works fine but there must be a better way to do this as I have to do this on every file.

Is there a way to do this once instead of having to do it for every single page load.

Please excuse me if this is a silly question but I am new to php and really just want to do things the best way from start.

Thank you to anyone that can help.

Comment: Mmmm... you usually indeed define an autoloader, and a pattern by which it includes the needed file(s), *once*. Repeating the process for every class sounds indeed wrong. Are you familiar with the autoloading examples in [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)? They may give you an idea on how to set this up

Comment: Are you saying that I only need to declare my autoloader in the index file.  Say i then move to the contact page or another page on the site then i can rely on the autoloader already being set?

Comment: @Pekka: my my, turns out that reading the frakkin manual really makes sense :)

Comment: no, you need to declare your autoloader in a central file that gets included by all other files that get called. The file is often called `bootstrap.php` or something - a central file that contains all the preparations necessary for every file @playcat yes, it indeed sometimes does! :) Took me many years to appreciate that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the __*autoload()* function in your index.php (which I am assuming is the entry point to your website). This should make autoload available to all scripts invoked thereafter. This is how I am maintaining my website which is running on Zend.

Answer (score 0):

Define everything you need and is common for all scripts in autoload.php, and load it from each script?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making a single script file that includes the standard classes, sets any standard constants, paths, sanitize GET/POST, etc.  Then include that once at the beginning of each file.  You may have exceptions, but it will be handly 90%+ of the time.

Also, look into __autoload.  It may be the more sophisticated solution to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The best method for doing this depends on how your application is organized.  If your app is just a collection of scripts, then the best way would be to simply overload the _autoload() function in a script and then include that script at the top of each file.  Example:

shared.php

```
function __autoload($classname){
   //Search through class file locations
}
```

script1.php

```
include('shared.php');
```

The other way of doing this is the best way.  I would suggest using an MVC framework of some kind or writing your own basic MVC.  This would make things a lot easier.  An MVC framework allows you to have a common entry point.  This is helpful at times like these because you can very easily overwrite the _autoload() function at the entry point, and it will take effect throughout your application.  That way, each time a class is created, you can look through all of your predefined directories to find the correct file to include.